# "Find Missing & Repeating Number" unable to compile on hackerrank suppose to use array list only not simple array

Tags: java, list

Encountered this program on hackerrank it was showing runtime error.

The relevant code block is shown below.

On simple array its working, but on lists its not working.
Lists are only accepted.

**Question statement on hackerrank:**

You are given a read-only array of N integers with values also in the range [1,N] both inclusive. Each integer appears exactly once except A which appears twice and B which is missing. The task is to find the repeating and missing numbers A and B where A repeats twice and B is missing.

Input Format

First line is the length of the array - n
Second line contains n integer that is elements of the array

Constraints

1 <= n <= 105
1 <= arr[i] <= n

Output Format

Print array of integers containing repeating and missing number respectively

Sample Input 0

3
3 1 3
Sample Output 0

3 2
Explanation 0

A = 3 , B = 2 Since 3 is appearing twice and 2 is missing

```
public static List<Integer> find_missing(List<Integer> arr) {
            int i;
        // Repeating number
        for (i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            int abs_val = Math.abs(arr.get(i));
            if (arr.get(abs_val - 1) > 0)
                arr.get(abs_val - 1) = -arr.get(abs_val - 1);
            else
                return abs_val;
        }
 //Missing number
        for (i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if (arr.get(i) > 0)
                return (i + 1);
        }
}
```

Comment: `arr.get(abs_val - 1) = -arr.get(abs_val - 1);` is actually wrong because here you are actually saying like **5 = -3** which is wrong , because lValue is indeed a value not a variable , use `arr.set(index, value);` instead , also from the code , in the prototype of the function , you are supposed to return a list but in the implementation you are returning integer

Comment: also , please post the original question on hacker rank for more clarification

Comment: Thanks for the feedback let me re-post the question accordingly with necessary details.

Comment: Hello Everyone , included the question statement as asked if any detail to be added please let me know, Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. "please guide me where is the mistake" is not much of a question; it suggests that you have not [attempted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to understand or narrow down the problem at all, and it makes the *assumption* that there is only one problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all `arr.get(abs_val - 1) = -arr.get(abs_val - 1);` is wrong because it's the same as saying **5 = -3** , as lValue is indeed a value not a variable , use `arr.set(index, value);` instead .
also in your code , you are using `Math.abs()` which isn'y necessary because in the question , it's said :

> 1 <= n <= 105 1 <= arr[i] <= n

so the values of **arr[i]** will always be positive.

so I edited the whole code of yours as it has many logic problems,

so for finding repeated numbers , what I do is to loop over the list , get every element then see if there is any other similar elements in the same array.

for finding repeated number , I loop over the numbers from 1 to N where N is entered by the user as specified by the problem above and check if every number is there in the list or not.

edited version of the code :

```
    package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> example = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            example.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }

        List<Integer> result = find_missing(example, n);
        for (Integer i : result)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    }

    public static List<Integer> find_missing(List<Integer> arr, int n) {
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        int i;
        // Repeating number
        for (i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); j++) {
                if (arr.get(j).equals(arr.get(i))){

                    if (temp.contains(arr.get(j)))
                        break;

                    temp.add(arr.get(i));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Missing number
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (!arr.contains(i))
                temp.add(i);
        }

        return temp;
    }

}
```

and here is some examples of the output test cases:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear Abdo Salm , Very grateful to you for the solution thanks a lot.